# If-else with multiple condition in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, variables, if-statement

For awhile, I've been trying to make this code work for this form's database, but it just wouldn't work properly.

[This is the form input without PI_ID.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQbWE.png)
[This is the form input with PI_ID.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlOWv.png)

```
$content = $_POST['cr_code'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_num'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_mon'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_year'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_modul'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_phase'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_pi_id'];
```

This output was faulty as the output will be `CR-001-08-18- -`, if I don’t want to input any module or phase, because the lines behind 18 are not supposed to be there.

Basically, the output is `CR-001-08-18-Marketing-PH1-PI1`, the Module(Marketing), Phase(PH1), and PI_ID(PI1) is optional to fill so it could either be:

- CR-001-08-18-Marketing(Module filled, Phase unfilled, PI_ID unfilled)
- CR-001-08-18-PH1(Module unfilled, Phase filled, PI_ID Unfilled)
- CR-001-08-18-PI(Module unfilled, Phase unfilled, PI_ID filled)

This was the code I where tried using if-else:

```js
$phase=$_GET['cr_phase'];
$modul=$_GET['cr_modul'];
$crpid=$_GET['cr_pi_id'];

if ($phase!='' && $modul='' && $crpid='')
{
 $content = $_POST['cr_code'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_num'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_mon'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_year'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_phase'];
}else if($phase='' && $modul!='' && $crpid='')
{
 $content = $_POST['cr_code'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_num'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_mon'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_year'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_modul'];
}else if($phase='' && $modul='' && $crpid=!'')
{
 $content = $_POST['cr_code'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_num'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_mon'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_year'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_pi_id'];
}else if($phase!='' && $modul!='' && $crpid!='')
{
 $content = $_POST['cr_code'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_num'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_mon'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_year'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_modul'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_phase'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_pi_id'];
}else
{
 $content = $_POST['cr_code'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_num'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_mon'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_year'];
}
```

But, it doesn't work as it just displays `CR-001-08-18` without showing the phase and module, even when I inputted the phase, module, and PI_ID.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

```
Only three if condition needed.Also check the method(GET or POST) you are using to submit the form and fetch the data accordingly or use $_REQUEST.

$phase=$_POST['cr_phase'];
$modul=$_POST['cr_modul'];
$crpid=$_POST['cr_pi_id'];

$values = "";
if($phase != '')
{
$values .= "-$phase";
}
if($modul != '')
{
$values .= "-$modul";
}
if($crpid != '')
{
$values .= "-$crpid";
}

    $content = $_POST['cr_code'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_num'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_mon'] . "-" . $_POST['cr_year'] . $values;
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! i tried changing the variable from $_GET to $_REQUEST, and using your if else statement, it worked wonderfully!

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement is similar to a series of IF statements on the same expression. In many occasions, you may want to compare the same variable (or expression) with many different values, and execute a different piece of code depending on which value it equals to. This is exactly what the switch statement is for.
 http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php